# Meaning of jersey in this sentence

Tags: american-english

What is the meaning of "jersey" in this sentence

> Kent proceeds to kick the shit out of Greg's jersey"

I don't know if it is slang or something about New jersey.

Comment: A jersey is an item of clothing: http://shop.mlb.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=1452620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close-fitting knitted item of clothing worn over ones arms and torso (a type of pullover/jumper depending on dialect) or an shirt or pullover that is part of a sporting uniform. (In this case a baseball jersey, but that's not something one could tell from the quoted sentence alone).

Answer (score 0):

It is a shirt worn in a sport usually.  It could be alluding that he is beating him at a sport.

Comment: He's not, he's literally kicking the jersey after Greg had taken it off. It's from a play, "reasons to be pretty" by Neil LaBute.

Comment: yes your right.

Comment: @JonHanna - Good call.  Didn't have any context.  It is a sports phrase (albeit not a commonly used one) used, especially in the 60-70s.

Comment: Yeah, the question doesn't give enough context to note it unless you've at least heard of the play (ironically, I saw the very scene mentioned in an arts show, and it's all I know about it).